# Definition of the Effective Particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory

We define the effective particle creation and annihilation operators which are collectively and commonly denoted by $\hat{q}_s$:

$$\hat{q}_s := \hat{U}_s \, \hat{q}_0 \, \hat{U}^\dagger_s $$

where $s$ is a renormalization group parameter, $0< s < \infty$, $\hat{U}_s$ is an unitary operator and  $\hat{q}_0$ collectively and commonly denotes the creation and annihilation operators in our familiar canonical theory. Due to the values of $s$, for each bare particle/particles state we get a family of effective particle/particles states. The particles associated with the effective particle/particles states are called the effective particles.

My question: Is $\hat{U}_s$ is a function of $\hat{q}_0$; i.e., $\hat{U}_s (\hat{q}_0)$  ?

Comment: Do you have a reference that would help to understand the context of your question ?

Comment: Simply google:

PERTURBATIVE FORMULAE FOR RELATIVISTIC
INTERACTIONS OF EFFECTIVE PARTICLES
by Stanisław D. Głazek